# Zend Framework 2 RestfulController with additional actions

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

I use the AbstractRestfulController for a controller in my ZF2-Application. This controller implements create(), update() etc.

Is it possible to have actions next to those REST-Functions?

E.g. I want to have: url.com/model/id to get the model (this works already), but i want to be able to call url.com/model/doSomething as well.

I tried using child_routes, but it did not work:

```
'car' => array(
                            'type'         => 'literal',
                            'options'      => array(
                                    'route'       => '/car',
                                    'defaults'    => array(
                                            'controller' => 'CarDealer\Controller\Car',
                                            'action' => 'index'
                                    ),
                            ),
                            'child_routes' => array(
                                    'rest'    => array(
                                            'type'    => 'segment',
                                            'options' => array(
                                                    'route'       => '[/:id]',
                                                    'constraints' => array(
                                                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                                                    ),
                                                    'defaults'    => array(
                                                            'controller' => 'CarDealer\Controller\Car',
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                    'actions' => array(
                                            'type'    => 'segment',
                                            'options' => array(
                                                    'route'       => '[/:action]',
                                                    'constraints' => array(
                                                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                                    ),
                                                    'defaults'    => array(
                                                            'controller' => 'CarDealer\Controller\Car',
                                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
```

I am pretty sure the above doesnt make so much sense, but I could not find the right hints to get things working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This goes against how REST works... You should probably map separate paths (aka resource URIs) to different actions via routing eventually. What you can do is using custom HTTP methods (verbs) instead

Comment: This was what I expected :) Thank you, I will use different controllers then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AbstractRestfulController won't dispatch to an arbitrary action method, so you should use a child route and another controller.

Comment: I don't understand you would you need another controller. A Literal route mapped to a specific action in the Restful controller works. For example, I have a use case where I need to get a count of how many **Item** objects I have. I created a Literal route mapping `/api/item/count` to `countAction()`, which returns `{count: #}`. This *seems* much better than using a completely separate controller or using `getList()` and figuring out the count client side. Is it ***necessarily*** "wrong" to add specific actions to a ZF2 Restful controller like this?

Comment: It's not wrong per-se. i.e. By definition you have a working solution :) However api/item/count is a different HTTP resource from api/item, so you are mixing the set of HTTP actions available on /api/item with a GET on /api/action/count into the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

use WildCard Routes to do something that is not excepted.
in controller get the wildcard parameters to make that action